# How to change the property of some buttons based on a DataGridView in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I achieve this? I have a form that contains a DataGridView and some buttons. When a new row is added to the DataGridView which contains the same Cabin number as the button Cabin number to say btnCabin1.BackColor = Color red; let's say.... DataGridView data is being pulled from an ArrayList(yeah I know but can't use a database for this purpose).
[image]

Comment: You can use a `List<class>` for the Items (ArrayList, really?), a `List<Button>` for the Buttons, use the former as the DataSource of a BindingSource, handle the `BindingSource.CurrentChanged` event to select the Button in the List that is at Index `[Cabin Number] - 1`, change its BackColor, store the current item, so the next selection you first change the previous item's BackColor to *normal state*, then change the BackColor of the selected Item to another Color. -- Or, you could handle the RowEnter event and take the index from `((int)CurrentRow.Cells["Cabin Number"].Value) - 1`.

Comment: Thanks for your time Jimi, the part with 2 lists is good although there would be a problem with BindingSource, but the RowEnter event was definitely the solution. Plus not much code to write! Appreciate